# Reloading partial with observe_field using Ajax triggers multiple events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototype

I have a form with 3 dropdowns - A, B, and C. When A changes, B should be updated with a new list of options and C should be cleared. When B changes, C should be updated with a new list of options.

I have partials for A, B, and C, and A and B both include the `observe_field` call to watch itself.

Every time A changes, B gets reloaded and a new observer is added. That means every time B changes, N+1 requests to reload C are triggered (where N is the number of times A has changed).

I've tried moving the `observe_field` call out of the partial that replaces the dropdown for B (placing it instead in the partial for A), but after the first change to A, B is no longer triggering events.

I've also tried adding a `$('b').stopObserving();` call to the `:before` of the observer on B, but that has the same effect - after the first change to A, events stop triggering on B.

Is there a way to make this work?

**Edit:**

Here is the Javascript that is generated by the `observe_field` calls:

```
new Form.Element.EventObserver('a', function(element, value) {
  $('b_loading_indicator').show();
  new Ajax.Updater('b',
    'http://localhost:3000/foos/b_control', {
      asynchronous: true,
      evalScripts: true,
      onComplete: function(request) { $('b_loading_indicator').hide(); },
      parameters: 'a_id=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&object_name=foo' + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('kH/TmOfvSKeNLxO4N0gxtqV0niNfAUlJ3guk6KAvPig=')
    });
});

new Form.Element.EventObserver('b', function(element, value) {
  $('c_loading_indicator').show();
  new Ajax.Updater('c', 
    'http://localhost:3000/foos/c_control', {
      asynchronous: true,
      evalScripts: true,
      onComplete: function(request) { $('c_loading_indicator').hide(); },
      parameters: 'a_id=' + encodeURIComponent($('a').value) + '&b_id=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&object_name=foo' + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('kH/TmOfvSKeNLxO4N0gxtqV0niNfAUlJ3guk6KAvPig=')
  });
});
```

Comment: Why use observe_field?  You can just use pure JS/JQuery and use the onchange event

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of observe_field? To avoid the direct use of Javascript?

Comment: I just do not see the need for using the helper.  Since it is ajaxified, you just need to update the lists based on the change.  Observe should do the same I just think it is simpler to just use JQuery with js.erb to re-render the lists.  Why is there N+1 requests?  It should only be one and just recreate the element so that it doesn't also trigger an onchange.

Comment: The helper just generates Javascript, so I don't see any difference between using a helper and writing the Javascript by hand. And that is exactly my question. Why are there N+1 requests when there should be only 1, and how do I fix it? :)

Comment: I believe it is happening because it creates a chain of events.  I believe the event is being triggered when you update B based on A's change and so forth.  That is why I thought the helper would make managing the events more complicated.  If you really want to see it in action update the helper method with debugging statements.

Comment: The Javascript that the helper is generating looks correct. It's re-adding or not re-adding the EventObserver that behaves strangely.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#section").bind("keyup", function() {
   data = {this.name: this.val()}; // the value of input that need to send to server
   $.get(url, data, // make ajax request
     function(html) { // function to handle the response
      $("#article_list").html(html); // change the inner html of update div
     });
   });
 });
```